# How to transform between the quaternions ( or ERYs)

Tags: ros, transform, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know I can transform my quaternion to ERY, and it seems easier to transform between ERYs because it's more direct. For example, I have a vector X (x,y,z) and its ERY is (0,0,a), and I have another vector Y(x',y',z') and ERY is (0,0,b), if I want to get Y by doing RX+T, can I get the rotation matrix R and transformation matrix T by using TF's function? Or if its not possible, how can I compute this? Thx a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229407/how-to-transform-between-the-quaternions-(-or-erys)/) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-18**:
@henschelx, which parameterization is ERY ? (roll,pitch,yaw) ?
For roscpp, you can have a look at tf::Transform::inverseTimes to get the difference between two tf::Transform objects.
For rospy, tf.transformations.py provides several utilities to get numpy matrices for transforms

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Posting the comment above as an answer since it was accepted :

For roscpp, you can have a look at tf::Transform::inverseTimes to get the difference between two tf::Transform objects. For rospy, tf.transformations.py provides several utilities to get numpy matrices for transforms

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0